# Compare two fields in kibana search

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, kibana, kibana-4, kibana-3

I have two fields one is timestamp which is associated with every record and one is expiryDate so I want to put a lucene query in the discover part search section such that it extract out the records for which expiry date > timestamp.
Can anyone help me in writing the query.
Consider online.timestamp as one field and online.expiry as another field.

Answer (score 2):

You can write the below query:-

```
{"constant_score":{"filter":{"script" : { "script" : "doc['online.expiry'].value > doc['online.timestamp'].value"}}}}
```

You may see an error while using above query such as:-

> ScriptException[scripts of type [inline], operation [search] and lang [groovy] are disabled]

To solve this error, edit your elasticsearch.yml file and enter the following property at the end:-

```
 script.inline:on
```

Then you can restart your Elasticsearch node or cluster and then query the same on Kibana which will fetch you desired records.

Comment: where should I apply the above query? I applied in script field but it throws `Failed to parse expression`

Comment: Hi @BilalUsean You should mention the query in Kibana search bar.
You would require to mention script.inline:on in elasticsearch.yml file.